# Spring Integration and ThreadPoolTaskExecutor

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, publish-subscribe, threadpoolexecutor

I'm working on a Spring Integration Project with annotation based configuration.
We inherited this project from another team and are trying to figure out if the ThreadPoolTaskExecutors are being used correctly. Below is a configuration of TaskExecutors:

```
@Bean
public TaskExecutor businessTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(30);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    pool.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return pool;
}

@Bean
public TaskExecutor eventTaskExecutor() {
    ThreadPoolTaskExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
    pool.setCorePoolSize(30);
    pool.setMaxPoolSize(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    pool.setQueueCapacity(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    return pool;
}
```

There are 5 TaskExecutor defined as indicate above. I'm not an expert but I know for sure they should be configured differently. These executors are used as follows:

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel inputChannel() {
    return new PublishSubscribeChannel(businessTaskExecutor());
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel outputChannel() {
    PublishSubscribeChannel outputChannel = new PublishSubscribeChannel(
            businessTaskExecutor());
    outputChannel
            .addInterceptor(new WireTap(eventTrackerChannel()));
    return outputChannel;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel eventTrackerChannel() {
    return new ExecutorChannel(eventTaskExecutor());
}
```

The input and output channels are used in some ServiceActivator. The eventTrackerChannel is used to split the Spring Integration flow and write some events on DB. These are just examples to understand how the project is structured.

Now the question is, are taskexecutors used correctly? If we eliminate the ThreadPoolTaskExecutors and they are not provided for the channels, should Spring manage the threads? Could there be problems in proceeding with this second approach?

I would like to learn Spring Integration as best I can and the answers to these questions would help a lot. I thank in advance who will help me understand this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

ThreadPool is a helper for us to not hold the main thread while some process that not depend of order is running. But it's not mandatory to use theses pools, but I am afraid that you may lose performance or increase the chance of failure without them, since these mechanisms normally has some kind of control besides pooling, like queuing events when the pool is full or reusing threads. Of course each case needs to be checked to see what fits better, but I believe if you don't need these events happening in a specifically order, I suggest you let this how it's.

What I've found different is how big your pools were set. But I don't know your requirements, so I can't conclude anything about this. What I normally see is the PoolSize something like 5 and maxSize like 10. Another thing is maybe you don't need each pool for each thing, one for all maybe it's suitable. But as I said, I can't say what's right or wrong, since each system has its own requirements.

The last detail that could be better is not hardcoding this setup, put in your `application.properties` these information like `maxThreadPoolSize=10` or `threadPoolSize=5` and then access it in the moment you setup the bean.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Your answer was very helpful in understanding some concepts. The corePoolSize initial value was 10 and we increased it due to slowdowns. In particular we noticed that requests were queued and not processed until threads became free. Furthermore, the machine on which the application is deployed was not under stress during the load moments. 
In fact the question related to the elimination of threadPools was to understand if perhaps it was possible to make the best use of the machine's resources, letting the framework manage the threads directly.